# Monitor JSF Managed Bean

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf, jsf-1.2

I want to monitor when a managed bean get created and destroyed. Specifically I want know when the constructor of the managed bean get called. I am in JSF 1.2 (ADF 11.1.1.6), so I don't have any @PostContstract or @PreDestroy. Is there any way?

Comment: This is handled by a PhaseListener. Refer to [Debug JSF lifecycle](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html) where BalusC heavily explains this.

Comment: Are you really using JSF 1.2? `@PostConstruct` is just available in JSF 1.2 (but not in JSF 1.0/1.1). I never used `@PreDestroy` on JSF 1.2, but on paper, it should work as well.